# Django: access manytomany field in template

Tags: django, django-templates

models.py

```
class Song(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', related_name='songs', blank=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

template.html

```
{% for tag in song.tags.all %}
   <i>{{ tag.name }}</i>
{% endfor %}
```

it turns out that there is nothing in the tag area, namely, the rendered html is nothing.
could you help me?

Comment: If you do the same thing in django shell for a song object, does that show up anything?

Comment: Yeah, as @ShangWang says, check if you can actually retrieve objects. It is not django's fault if you don't have any.

Comment: The code above is minified one. I have other fields like name, etc.. I can see my songs in admin site and other fields displayed correctly.

Comment: I think what the first two commenters were trying to say is if you can `song.tags.all()` does not return an empty list in the shell.

Comment: yes, like you guys said, there is nothing in `song.tags.all()`.I have one tag on admin site but I didn't select it. It is fixed now. Thank you very much.